# Extract data from the column

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have the dataframe , it contains 2 columns from the sencod column i want to create the 3rd column

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5], 'col2': ['False_False','ab_ba_False','ab_ba_False','bca_False_abc_False_cd','bca_False_abc_False_cd','bca_False_abc_False_cd','False_bca_False_abc_cde','False_bca_False_abc_cde','False_bca_False_abc_cde','as_False']}); df1


Input
   Index                    col2
0      1             False_False
1      2             ab_ba_False
2      2             ab_ba_False
3      3  bca_False_abc_False_cd
4      3  bca_False_abc_False_cd
5      3  bca_False_abc_False_cd
6      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde
7      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde
8      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde
9      5  as_False
```

IF column contains False the outout is be False oresle it take each value from the second column.

```
OutPut:



  Index                    col2   col3
0      1             False_False    False
1      2             ab_ba_False    ab
2      2             ab_ba_False    ba
3      3  bca_False_abc_False_cd    bca
4      3  bca_False_abc_False_cd    abc
5      3  bca_False_abc_False_cd    cd
6      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde   bca
7      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde   abc
8      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde   cde
9      5  as_False                  as
```

Comment: How do you want the values in col3 to be populated? want to split the string on _ and then populate the list excluding False

Comment: please clarify more how you want to derive the third column from the second column.

Comment: You mean if col2 contains only False then  False? Also , on the else part, How are you deciding which value to add in col3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working if same values per group by column `Index`, so processing only first value of column per group.

First `split` and filter out `False` values and then are 3 conditions for general solution:

```
def f(x):
    a = [y for y in x.iat[0].split('_') if y != 'False']
    if len(x) == len(a):
        return a
    elif len(x) > len(a):
        return a + ['False'] * (len(x) - len(a))
    elif len(x) < len(a):
        return a[:len(x)]

df1['col3'] = df1.groupby('Index')['col2'].transform(f)
print (df1)
   Index                     col2   col3
0      1              False_False  False
1      2              ab_ba_False     ab
2      2              ab_ba_False     ba
3      3   bca_False_abc_False_cd    bca
4      3   bca_False_abc_False_cd    abc
5      3   bca_False_abc_False_cd     cd
6      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde    bca
7      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde    abc
8      4  False_bca_False_abc_cde    cde
9      5                 as_False     as
```

Comment: Index 5 is missing in the output -as

Comment: the dataframe you have created does not have that row